# page content is not visible in right side of screen in responsive mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have designed one responsive web page. There are a fixed top bootstrap navbar and main content area. In desktop, it is showing perfectly fine. If I change the responsive layout into mobile devices by using chrome dev tools. Some portion of the main content area is hidden on the right side of the screen. If I do horizontal scrolling then I can see the main content.

How can I see the main content full whenever I change different device's width?

Here you can see the screenshot where it is hided
[image]

```
    #mainbody{
      float:left;
            padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
            overflow:hidden;
            max-width: 500px;
}
```

in my page i am using this:

```
<div id="mainbody"> main content here....</div>
```

Please tell me how the main content will be visible full without cutting by the right side for any mobile device?

Comment: remove overflow or change it to auto

Comment: Is it possible to make it smaller or wider based on screen width? How to do that?

Comment: anywhere that we can test it?  it worked when you removed the overflow?

Comment: Nopes... hard luck. can i use media queries?

Comment: you can do it with media queries but also you can try flex and try last thing to set the width in percentge

Comment: can you suggest me that for resolution (375X667) ?

Comment: Why are you floating things in a Bootstrap layout? Just use the layout grid. Also, we'd need to see your page markup to help.

Comment: Use Bootstrap grid or jus flexbox, why you fixing your mainarea size?